# SQL converting backup size columns

Tags: sql-server, database, backup, type-conversion, numeric

So I have this part of SQL script which I need to convert the two columns into `2 decimal point`.

```
convert (numeric(10,2),
ROUND(SUM(msdb.dbo.backupset.compressed_backup_size)*8/1024, 0)) 
as 'Compressed_Backup_Size in MB' ,
SUM(msdb.dbo.backupset.backup_size/1024)/1024 
as 'Backup_Size in GB'
```

My question is how do I get the two backup size columns to show the right value, I tried the conversion but the result it's still 894512.00 instead of 89.45 MB.. I have looked everywhere and they telling me to convert the numeric but still doesn't work for me. Help please

Answer (score 1):

You can try this query for getting size in gb

```
select convert(decimal(18,3),(sum(backup_size))/1024/1024/1024) as SizeinGB
 from msdb.dbo.backupset
```